# Spring Web "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException] with root cause" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, transactions

I have a dynamic web project which I did not use Maven (so, I do not have pom.xml). My controller works for HelloWorldController which I created for testing purposes. I'm getting following error which I thought as related with service or JpaDao classes. I will also add those files. If there is anything else you need, I can also add and update my post. Thanks in advance.

I'm having such an error log:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/Spring3MVC] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1778)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.spitter.web.dao.JpaSpitterDao.getRecentSpittle(JpaSpitterDao.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.getRecentSpittle(Unknown Source)
    at com.spitter.web.service.SpitterServiceImpl.getRecentSpittles(SpitterServiceImpl.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35.getRecentSpittles(Unknown Source)
    at com.spitter.web.controller.HomeController.showHomePage(HomeController.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

JpaSpitterDao.java:

```
package com.spitter.web.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.spitter.web.domain.Spitter;
import com.spitter.web.domain.Spittle;


@Repository("spitterDao")
@Transactional
public class JpaSpitterDao implements SpitterDao {
  private static final String RECENT_SPITTLES = 
      "SELECT s FROM Spittle s";
  private static final String ALL_SPITTERS =
      "SELECT s FROM Spitter s";
  private static final String SPITTER_FOR_USERNAME = 
      "SELECT s FROM Spitter s WHERE s.username = :username";
  private static final String SPITTLES_BY_USERNAME = 
      "SELECT s FROM Spittle s WHERE s.spitter.username = :username";

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em; //<co id="co_injectEM"/>

  public void addSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
    em.persist(spitter); //<co id="co_useEM"/>
  }

  public Spitter getSpitterById(long id) {
    return em.find(Spitter.class, id); //<co id="co_useEM"/>
  }

  public void saveSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
    em.merge(spitter); //<co id="co_useEM"/>
  }
//<end id="java_contextualJpaDao"/> 
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<Spittle> getRecentSpittle() {
    return (List<Spittle>) em.createQuery(RECENT_SPITTLES).
        getResultList();
  }

  public void saveSpittle(Spittle spittle) {
    em.persist(spittle);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<Spittle> getSpittlesForSpitter(
          Spitter spitter) {
    return (List<Spittle>) em.createQuery(SPITTLES_BY_USERNAME).
        setParameter("username", spitter.getUsername()).
        getResultList();
  }


  public Spitter getSpitterByUsername(String username) {
    return (Spitter) em.createQuery(SPITTER_FOR_USERNAME).
        setParameter("username", username).
        getSingleResult();
  }

  public void deleteSpittle(long id) {
    try {
      em.remove(getSpittleById(id));
    } catch(DataAccessException e) {}
  }

  public Spittle getSpittleById(long id) {
    return em.find(Spittle.class, id);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<Spitter> findAllSpitters() {
    return em.createQuery(ALL_SPITTERS).getResultList();
  }
}
```

SpitterServiceImpl.java (Service implementation):

```
package com.spitter.web.service;

import static java.lang.Math.min;
import static java.util.Collections.reverse;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.spitter.web.dao.SpitterDao;
import com.spitter.web.domain.Spitter;
import com.spitter.web.domain.Spittle;

@Service("spitterService")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class SpitterServiceImpl implements SpitterService {

  public void saveSpittle(Spittle spittle) {
    spittle.setWhen(new Date());
    spitterDao.saveSpittle(spittle);
  }

  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true)
  public List<Spittle> getRecentSpittles(int count) {
    List<Spittle> recentSpittles = 
        spitterDao.getRecentSpittle();

    reverse(recentSpittles);

    return recentSpittles.subList(0, 
            min(49, recentSpittles.size()));
  }

  public void saveSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
    if(spitter.getId() == null) {
      spitterDao.addSpitter(spitter);
    } else {
      spitterDao.saveSpitter(spitter);
    }
  }

  @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true)
  public Spitter getSpitter(long id) {
    return spitterDao.getSpitterById(id);
  }

  public void startFollowing(Spitter follower, Spitter followee) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
  }

  public List<Spittle> getSpittlesForSpitter(Spitter spitter) {
    return spitterDao.getSpittlesForSpitter(spitter);
  }

  public List<Spittle> getSpittlesForSpitter(String username) {
    Spitter spitter = spitterDao.getSpitterByUsername(username);
    return getSpittlesForSpitter(spitter);
  }

  public Spitter getSpitter(String username) {
    return spitterDao.getSpitterByUsername(username);
  }

  public void deleteSpittle(long id) {
    spitterDao.deleteSpittle(id);
  }

  public List<Spitter> getAllSpitters() {
    return spitterDao.findAllSpitters();
  }

  @Autowired
  SpitterDao spitterDao;

  public Spittle getSpittleById(long id) {
    return spitterDao.getSpittleById(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: have you added antlr lib in classpath of project?

Comment: No, I do not have such library in my Lib folder. Should I include that?

Comment: yes include it as error itself saying that class is not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException shows antlr lib missing. Add it and itss done :)